# presentViewController not supporting orientation in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, orientation, ios6

I am using this code

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)])
    {
        [self presentViewController:navigationControllerCustom animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        [self presentModalViewController:navigationControllerCustom animated:YES];
    }
```

My application has two orientation Portrait and Portrait upside down. This code works well with iOS 5.1, but orientation does not work on iOS 6

I have also added this code on my `navigationControllerCustom` class

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ive got the same problem in my apps I compiled for iOS 6; all orientations work except for UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown; its weird.

Comment: @MrJre Any solution on same as this is really weird.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You must include this in you application delegate:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```

Also make sure the View Controller's both have the following, works fine for me.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```

The documentation also says that `UINavigationController's` doesn't query its top View Controller for orientations supported, although an Apple engineer over on the Developer Forums did say so... it seems that it does not. Therefore you should add a category for `UINavigationController`, this is the one I use:

```
#import "UINavigationController+autorotate.h"

@implementation UINavigationController (autorotate)

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}

@end
```

For more information how AutoRotate works on iOS 6 [check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12623916/662605)

Comment: The UINavigationController category was sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added, but it is not working, any other thing I am missing.

Comment: In your Info.plist under supported interface orientations, do you have portrait and portrait upside-down listed?

Answer (score 1):

Just copy paste that snippet above your code

```
@implementation UINavigationController (rotation)
//temp hack for iOS6, this allows passing supportedInterfaceOrientations to child viewcontrollers.
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to enable or disable rotation for all view controllers you don't need to subclass UINavigationController. 
  Instead use:

```
   -(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
```

in your AppDelegate.

If you plan to support all orientations in your app but different orientations on PARENT View Controllers (UINavigationController stack for example) you should use

```
   -(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
```

in combination with the following methods in your Parent View Controller.

```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
```

and

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
```

But if you plan to have different orientation settings in different CHILDREN ViewControllers in the same navigation stack (like me) you need to check the current ViewController in the navigation stack.

I've created the following in my UINavigationController subclass:

```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    int interfaceOrientation = 0;

    if (self.viewControllers.count > 0)
    {
        id viewController;
        DLog(@"%@", self.viewControllers);
        for (viewController in self.viewControllers)
        {
            if ([viewController isKindOfClass:([InitialUseViewController class])])
            {
                 interfaceOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
            }
            else if ([viewController isKindOfClass:([MainViewController class])])
            {
                 interfaceOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
            }
            else
            {
                 interfaceOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
            }
        }
    }
    return interfaceOrientation;
}
```

Since you cannot control anymore from children ViewControllers the rotation settings of presented view controller you must somehow intercept what view controller is currently in the navigation stack. So that's what I did :). Hope that helps !

Comment: Thanks @codeFi, your suggestions fixed my problems. I've been struggling quite a lot when migrating from iOS5 to iOS6 with the various device-orientation issues. You make my day!

Answer (score 1):

Subclass UINavigationController and override the shouldAutorotate and supportedInterfaceOrientations like this:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return self.topViewController.shouldAutorotate;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
     return self.topViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations;
}
```

And now you can control your orientation is each ViewController. Just override the two methods in each ViewController.