# ios 6 presentViewController

Tags: ios6

Orientation is not working in presentViewController. Even am using category for UINavigationController. supportedInterfaceOrientations method is called but no changes. In Base viewcontroller shouldAutorotate method returns YES. Where am having the following code.

**I am using this code.**

```
ViewControllerOne *viewOne = [[ViewControllerOne alloc]init];

UINavigationController *navCtrl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewOne];
navCtrl.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

[self presentViewController:navCtrl animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance...

Comment: possible duplicate of [presentViewController not supporting orientation in iOS 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566780/presentviewcontroller-not-supporting-orientation-in-ios-6)

Answer (score 1):

Which simulator ios 5 or ios 6 are you using? 
Post some more code.
Also see this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537541/supportedinterfaceorientations-method-not-working-on-ios-6-uiviewcontroller/12623916#12623916)

Replaced this line code in appDelegate:

```
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
```

by this line:

```
[window setRootViewController:viewController];
```

check for both iOS 5 and 6

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)])
        {
            [self presentViewController:navigationControllerCustom animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
        else
        {
            [self presentModalViewController:navigationControllerCustom animated:YES];
        }
```

Try using for rotation

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```