# ios6 autorotation portraitupsidedown to portrait

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios4, autorotate

Please don't suggest me it is a bad idea to have the rotation at ios 4.3-6.0 in 1 build, because I told to many times and didn't listen to me.

At project settings I have setted all interface orientations to be supported, just to be sure.

Right now  I am testing on ios6 with iphone4. Starting at app delegate it is a code, like this:

```
mainController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

navigationController=[[RotatingNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainController];          
navigationController.navigationBar.hidden =true;

// ios: 4 and 5
//[window addSubview:navigationController.view];

//ios6:
window.rootViewController = navigationController;

[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

So I did 2 custom classes, which are recommended in may cases for autorotations, and for they the problem is solved.

The RotatingNavigationController is a custom `UINavigationController` has a bit ugly code, but I have collected this parts from this forum, so it should be allowed to post it:

```
@implementation RotatingNavigationController

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {        
        self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
        [self.view setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth)];
    }
    return self;
}

// ios6 require this method for rotation detection, available from ios5, ios4.3 not available: sux
//- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
//{
    //UIInterfaceOrientation statusBarOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

    //[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]     postNotificationName:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification     object:nil];

//    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self                                              selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)                                                  name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification                                                object:nil];

    /*
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(statusBarOrientation)){
        [self willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: statusBarOrientation duration: 0.3 ];
    }
    else{
        [self willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: statusBarOrientation duration: 0.3 ];
    }
    */
//}

//ios 4.3 and ios 5.0, at ios6 it isn't called by iOS...sux
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    [self.visibleViewController willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
}

// //ios 4.3 and ios 5.0, at ios6 need different methods, which sux
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
} 

//Autorotation is changing in iOS 6. In iOS 6, the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method of UIViewController is deprecated. In its place, you should use the supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow: and shouldAutorotate methods.


// ios6
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

// ios6
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
// ios6
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
@end
```

- this should generate the autorotation notifications properly, I think he it does his job.

The `MainViewController` is a custom `UIViewController`.

just to be sure I have copy-pasted the code:

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    //    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    return YES;
}

// ios6:
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

// ios6
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

His job is to change the different UIViewController based on device state ( rotations )

I have somewhere a Menu screen, which has different xib, but h and m file too ( because has different elements, which doesn't appear in Portait or Landscape. ( I don't have the power to change the whole architecture )

A part of the code - and here should be some problem, I think is below in this Maincontroller:

```
#pragma mark
#pragma mark Rotation
- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    UIInterfaceOrientation statusBarOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation; 

    if(deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp || deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown){
        if(debug){
            NSLog(@"Nothing to change because it is gone to Flat");
        }
        return;
    }
NSArray *viewControllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers];

if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation)){

        //if(debug)
        //    NSLog(@"Portait -> Landscape size : %3.0fw, %3.0fh", self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
        id lastviewController = viewControllers.lastObject;
        // check what is there:
        if([lastviewController isKindOfClass:[MenuController class]]){                 
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:menuLandscape animated:NO];
            NSLog(@"poped Menu Portrait, pushed Menu Landscape");
        }
...
else if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(deviceOrientation)){
    //else if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(statusBarOrientation)){

        //if(debug)
        //    NSLog(@"Landscape -> Portait , size : %3.0fw, %3.0fh", self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
        id lastviewController = viewControllers.lastObject;
        // check what is there:
        if([lastviewController isKindOfClass:[MenuLandscapeController class]]){
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];            
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:menuPortait animated:NO];
        } 
...
```

The problem is: the landscape is taken out and is pushed the portait, when is upside down, but that portait aren't rotating and it shows a broken layout.

How can I wake up that controller and tell him is time to rotate, because it isn't in portrait mode?

Thanks any suggestion related to my question of any improvement beside of architecture change.

Update:

at app delgate doesn't helped adding the:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

code from other answer: [presented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566780/presentviewcontroller-not-supporting-orientation-in-ios-6)

Update2:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation statusBarOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
```

doesn't want to take the `UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown = UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown` value for some reason, I think that need to be solved.

Update3:
  Read very carefully twice and third the [ios6 release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/_index.html)

> The system determines whether an orientation is supported by
>   intersecting the value returned by the app’s
>   supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow: method with the value
>   returned by the supportedInterfaceOrientations method of the top-most
>   full-screen controller.

- now read again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this category to viewcontroller which doesn't rotate

```
@implementation UINavigationController(Rotation)

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

@end
```

Comment: thanks for trying to help me, but: for sure isn't good, because only the bottom controller is taken in consideration, which are rotation. The only problem it is with upside down. I am 99.99% sure it is related with ios 6.0 or ios 6.0.1 which I have compiled, because with the previous version it was working  my code. Now it seems I need to rotate manually those 2 portait  controllers. Upvoted this answer for trying to help me!

Comment: I had a problem with a viewcontroller which i put into the navigation the same as you did. Also there was everything ok with rotating except PortraitUpsideDown. This helped me

Comment: Right now I have tryed, and doesn't working for me. At viewDidAppear need to rotate in different angles, based on previous state and current device state

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't able to figure out how I could override this method. I needed to lock the orientation change based on case. :)