# I don't know how to do Portrait and Upside down in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios6, uiinterfaceorientation

I am using:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait; 

}
```

How would I use this for Portrait and Upside down in iOS6?

this works for landscape left `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft`

and this for Landscape right `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight`

and this for both landscapes `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to return a valid bitmask of the orientations you wish to support:

For portrait and portrait upside down:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);

}
```

You can see a list of the [supported orientation masks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIInterfaceOrientationMask)

It's important to note also, that you need to list portrait upside down in your supported orientations as well:

[image]

Comment: I had already done that in Project settings and thanks for the code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the bitwise OR operator for each supported orientation.

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait |
        UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown; 
}
```

Add another bitwise OR for each orientation you want to support. Typically, when you see a constant with the word "mask" in it, they are meant to be combined in this way.

Answer (score 1):

I had me too the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704218/ios6-autorotation-portaitupsidedown-to-portait)

Your should solve your problem too.

- allow the rotations
- at top components need to allow again

Watch carefully those methods, seems similar, but aren't