# Keyboard is upside down in UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios6, uiinterfaceorientation

I'm trying to get my app updated to work with the new iPhone 5, and some of my views are dropping the keyboard down from the top of the view instead of the bottom. Here's an image to better illustrate:

[image]

This worked before iOS 6.0, so I'm guessing it must be something in the new API that is causing this bug to shine. I am using the following code to support orientations in the UIVeiwController:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
   // Return YES for supported orientations
   return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || 
           interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
   return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Has anyone else seen a similar problem? Thanks!

Comment: is it in a custom view / window and a transform has been applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537541/supportedinterfaceorientations-method-not-working-on-ios-6-uiviewcontroller). My problem was fixed by changing one line of code where I was setting up my root UI view controller.

Changing this line:

```
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
```

to this:

```
[window setRootViewController:viewController];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to replicate your issue but it works good for me on iOS6. My suggestion might be not very helpful but review that delegate, the synthesize and all the features match.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew, I also find that the method shouldAutoROtateToInterfaceOrientation was deprecated in iOS 6.

Anyways, I saw you solved your issue.