# Why does autorotation happen in iOS 6 but not iOS 5?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, autolayout

I have a general question to iOS 6 and AutoLayout in the Simulator.
My app is targeting iOS 5 and iOS 6 as well. I need to switch-off AutoLayout in StoryBoard otherwise the app is crashing in the iOS 5 simulator (since AutoLayout is supported first with iOS6). 
But when I start the iOS 6 simulator all views are rotating and all subviews are resizing accordingly. Using iOS 5 simulator all views doesn't rotate with changing the device orientation.

Would that happen on real devices as well? So, even with switched-off AutoLayout option in Storyboard would all the views rotate with the device orientation with iOS 6 and better on a real device?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like an autorotation question more then an AutoLayout question. You are aware that iOS 6 introduced a different autorotation system then iOS 5 right?

Comment: @Daniel, you are actually the only one answering my question. You should post an answer that I can accept. Is autorotation the default behavior for iOS 6? And why are the views resizing properly in the iOS 6 simulator with AutoLayout not activated? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like someone beat me to it. :(

Comment: I'm sorry! But thank you anyway. There will be another chance...

Comment: This might still be of some interest to you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12623916/662605

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple changed how autorotation works in iOS 6.

If you create a project in Xcode 4.6, Xcode sets it up to use the iOS 6 autorotation API.  The project template allows portrait, landscape-left, and landscape-right orientations (and upside-down portrait in an iPad app).  So when you run the app on iOS 6 (device or simulator), the app allows interface rotation.

When you run that project on iOS 5 (on either the simulator or the device), the system ignores the iOS 6 autorotation API and looks for the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method on your view controller.  Since Xcode 4.6 didn't create that method (and presumably you didn't add it), the system uses the default implementation, which is only returns `YES` for portrait orientation.  Thus on iOS 5 you don't get any interface rotation.

The simple solution, if you don't want interface rotation, is to go to your target's Summary and turn off the landscape orientations.

[image: target summary with landscape buttons called out]

You can learn more from several official sources:

- [The “ Handling View Rotations” section of the *UIViewController Class Reference*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW57).
- [The “UIKit” section of the iOS 6.0 Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012166-CH1-SW13).
- [“The Evolution of View Controllers on iOS” video from WWDC 2012](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=236).

Comment: Hello Rob. Excellent answer as always from you. Thank you very much! You helped me a lot. Where do I get that kind of generall information when Apple introduces changes like these?

Comment: Read the release notes.  Watch the WWDC videos.  At least watch the “What's New in XXX” videos.

Answer (score 2):

Like @Patrick Tescher said, you can't use Auto Layout in iOS 5.

You should also consider the fact that only 6% of the users have iOS 5, as of June '13. At the same time, iOS 6 adoption is at 93% ([source](http://www.imore.com/ios-6-used-93-ios-customers)). This is a very high number. So depending on your situation, perhaps you don't have to make your app iOS 5 compatible in the first place. Spending twice the development time on a feature to make it work for 6% users may not be the best use of one's time. Unless it's a business decision and you get paid in either case :)

Comment: This is not 100% true. I have an iPhone 4S that is still running iOS 5.0 (yup you heard right) and almost every top 300 apps that I have installed from appstore run on my device. That means developers are still supporting iOS 5.0 or lower. I do it too. Almost all my apps are both iOS 5.0 and iOS 6.0 compatible and I do notice higher return on apps that support both 5.0 and above

Comment: BlackRider, thanks for your post. I know that AutoLayout can't be used in iOS 5. Do you know why the views are still resizing properly in the iOS 6 simulator with AutolAyout not activated?

Comment: It could be because their `autoresizingMask` is configured correctly. Your views can still resize without AutoLayout, but then they always resize relative to their parent. Whereas with AutoLayout, they can also resize relative to their peer views.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support iOS 5 you should not use auto layout. Auto layout is only supported in iOS 6 and later.

You can technically have two storyboards and load one for iOS 5 and one for iOS 6 but you would be duplicating a lot of work. Best to just hold back on Auto Layout until you can remove iOS 5 support.