# Presentingviewcontroller of modalviewcontroller not rotating

Tags: iphone, ios6, ios7

I have presented `ViewController2` from `viewController1` and rotated the device , `modalviewcontroller (viewcontroller2)` only rotating according to rotation but background presenting view controller is not rotating.

```
UIViewController *viewController2 = [UIViewController alloc]init];
self.presentationstyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;    
[self presentViewController:viewController2 animated:YES];
```

please can anyone help me....

Comment: Without showing your modal view, did your viewcontroller screen rotates  with device orientation?

Answer (score 0):

Please do a research on stackoverflow itself before posting repeated questions. However I will provide you right pointers.

1. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/563983/1307844) is what you need to think about.
2. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12588038/1307844) on the post from stackOverflow.

Comment: Why don't you flag this post as duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and maybe I can save others some time.

The short answer: I couldn't find a real solution.

The long answer: I consider it a bug. There are surprisingly few posts to find in the internet, so probably there are some yet unknown side-conditions to trigger this behavior. 
It only affects *UIModalPresentationCurrentContext*. If you don't need semi-transparence you can go for the other modes like *UIModalPresentationFullScreen* which work.

The resulting state is quite messy: *statusBarOrientation* reports the gui-orientation correct. Also the bounds have changed. Calling *setNeedsLayout* will result in a layout matching the real orientation in size but oriented the wrong way...

maybe it can be fixed setting a transformation to the view or by triggering the framework to reconsider its orientation by adding and removing a view with respective orientation-support-flags, or some other ugly workaround(Sadly there is no way of telling the framework directly to change orientation)

I resorted to a solution that uses *addSubview instead* of *presentViewController*.